# Parameter marshaling protocol homework for RPC call?

Tags: c++, c, rpc

I have a homework to build on paper a parameter marshaling protocol to be suited to call a method with one variable, or with an array (like a polymorphism).

procedure(var1)
procedure(array1)

How would you define the protocol? How about the method in C++

Comment: If its homework, shouldn't you be doing it yourself? At the very least, you should come up with a tentative solution and then ask here for advice on specific points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make the functions with Object parameters. 
i.e

`void myFunction(void* param, int paramType)
{
if(paramType == definedTypes[0] )
{
// do stuff
}
else if(paramType == definedTypes[1])
{
//do something else
}
}`

you pass 2 parameters: in the first your object, in the second the type of your object,
you have to define for example in an array what types of data are you interested in.